# Is there a difference between writing stored procedures in visual studio 2010 and SQL express 2005?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Is there a difference in terms of performance or flexibility? 
Is it a waste of time writing stored procedures in SQL express 2005 and importing them to VS2010?

Comment: What do you mean by importing them to VS2010 ??

Comment: What do you mean by importing stored procedures to VS 2010? It makes no difference, whatever approach you use, stored procedures will be executed and stored in database.

Comment: i thought you could import them.. hmmm. Is executing an SQL Statement/Stored procedure faster in SQL express, can i connect VS2010 to SQL express  then, so the procedures will be excecuted in SQL express and i will get the data straight into my VS2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about using  VS2010 to create the stored procedures inside of SQL Express, no.  They're performing the same operation, namely execute a `CREATE PROCEDURE` against the server.

If you're talking about creating a procedure in SQL Server versus executing the SQL of said procedure from within code in VS2010 (using ado.net or something), then there is a world of difference.

Comment: i want to code a stored procedure in database..and refer to it through my code, by calling it , and feeding it into my sqlCommand, (instead of writing the whole algorithm of stored procedured by hand and concating it to make it an sqlCommand!!

Comment: Then there's no difference between doing it with SSMS and Visual Studio.  They're both going to end up executing the same `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.  As far as performance goes, unless you're doing something incredibly complex, there probably won't be that much of a difference, honestly.  The decision of Stored Procedure vs SQL in code is more of a design choice.  (IE, where do you store your business logic.)  There are vehement proponents and detractors on both sides of the debate.

Answer (score 5):

Using Visual Studio to manage your stored procedure will make it easy to use source control systems such as [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) to track changes to your stored procedures.

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding your stored procedures using the server browser in VS2010 it will still save them in your database, so no difference there